# React on switching tablet mode

Tags: windows, message

I allow users to switch my application's UI between a usual and a touch optimized view. But at the moment this has to be triggered manually. Is there any way to get an automatic trigger from system such as a message or something that notifies my application when the OS switches to tablet mode?

I already tried to receive the message WM_SETTINGCHANGE as I found in this official continuum article:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn917883(v=vs.85).aspx

Unfortunately I don't receive this message by switching UI mode in System Settings in Windows 10.

Do I have any other options?